# MATCH blocks for Neo4j, to prevent "null property value"-error

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I'm creating Person labelled nodes from a JSON, in Neo4j, with something like this (JSON is blank because of privacy/to much data):

```
WITH [] AS contacts
UNWIND contacts AS contact
```

But sometimes the person data doesn't have a first name and or last name,
so this query fails:

```
MERGE(personBind:Person {first_name: contact.first_name, last_name: contact.last_name})
```

It gives this error:

```
Cannot merge node using null property value
```

Is it possible to have a `MATCH`, with something like these blocks in it:

```
NOT MATCH
 CANT CREATE (Don't do something with person, but make other stuff)
 CAN CREATE (Make person and relations to person, and make other stuff)
ON MATCH (Make relations to person, and make other stuff)
```

This is the other code, that I need to use,
but is to "attached" to person (Sometimes will fail):

```
FOREACH (addr IN contact.addrs |
            MERGE addrPath=((zipBind:ZipCode {zipcode: addr.zipcode})-[nz:NUMBER_IN_ZIPCODE]->(houseBind:House {number: addr.housenumber})<-[ns:NUMBER_IN_STREET]-(streetBind:Street))

            MERGE(personBind)-[:WORKS_AT]->(houseBind)
            )

        FOREACH( phoneValue IN contact.phone | MERGE(phoneBind:Phone {number: phoneValue.value}) MERGE(personBind)-[:REACHABLE_BY]->(phoneBind) )
        FOREACH( emailValue IN contact.email | MERGE(emailBind:Email {email: emailValue.value}) MERGE(personBind)-[:REACHABLE_BY]->(emailBind) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break your query up into two parts: first, address the universal parts (the contact data), then filter your query for people who have a first and last name and merge the other components.

```
UNWIND [] AS contact
WITH contact
UNWIND contact.addrs  AS addr
MERGE (zipBind:ZipCode {zipcode: addr.zipcode})
MERGE (streetBind:Street)  # does this need properties, like a name?
MERGE (streetBind) - [:NUMBER_IN_STREET] ->(houseBind:House {number: addr.housenumber})
MERGE (zipBind) -[:NUMBER_IN_ZIPCODE]-> (houseBind)
WITH contact, COLLECT(houseBind) AS houseBinds
UNWIND contact.phone AS phoneValue
MERGE(phoneBind:Phone {number: phoneValue.value})
WITH contact, houseBinds, COLLECT(phoneBind) AS phoneBinds
UNWIND contact.email AS emailValue 
    MERGE(emailBind:Email {email: emailValue.value})
WITH contact, houseBinds, phoneBinds, COLLECT(emailBind) AS emailBinds

<NOW FILTER FOR CONTACTS WITH PERSON DATA>

WHERE exists(contact.first_name) AND EXISTS(contact.last_name)
MERGE(personBind:Person {first_name: contact.first_name, last_name: contact.last_name})

FOREACH( housebind IN housebinds|MERGE(personBind)-[:WORKS_AT]->(houseBind))

    FOREACH( phoneBind IN phoneBinds | MERGE(personBind)-[:REACHABLE_BY]->(phoneBind) )

    FOREACH( emailBind IN emailBinds | ) MERGE(personBind)-[:REACHABLE_BY]->(emailBind) )
```

If you need rows that don't have Person names later in the query, you can change the filter step to create two lists, one that has names, one that doesn't, but that's more complicated than your question requires.

EDITED: Your `Street` nodes have no properties, so this query is going to find the same street for every row. Is there something you want to assign there?

Comment: The previous code gave a `houseBind` value missing error. Your edit works, I only had to fix syntax things: add ")" after `addrPath`, and remove "|" after `UNWIND`. I understand now that you can "collect" data with `WITH` and pass it to the next blocks. First time I see a combination of `WITH` and `WHERE` :)

Comment: Mm, I also see blank nodes for `Street` in my graph, maybe because the `House.number` is sometimes newly introduced.

Comment: Thanks for the typo catching. I went ahead and broke down the `addrPath` merge as well for you, should solve your street problem. Whenever you merge a pattern, you match the _entire_ pattern or you create the _entire_ pattern, so if any part of that addr pattern is new (number, zip, or street), you're gonne end up with duplicates making it all at once. Try and merge smaller patterns and use aliases to tie them together.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of foreach and case:

```
UNWIND [ {lastName: 'Fam1', firstName: 'Nam1'}, {lastName: 'Fam2'} ] 
       as contact
FOREACH( x in CASE WHEN ( NOT contact.lastName is NULL AND 
                          NOT contact.firstName is NULL
              ) THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (personBind:TMP:Person {first_name: contact.firstName, 
                                last_name: contact.lastName}
  )
)
```

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/06/17/neo4j-load-csv-handling-conditionals/